# Thunder Client: simplest way to add script to request

Tags: vscode-extensions, thunderclient

I try to figure out how to **add custom code** to my request similar way to pre-request script in Postman like:

```js
const items = JSON.parse(pm.collectionVariables.get('items'))

const randomItem = _.sample(items)

pm.variables.set('randomItemId', randomItem.id)
pm.variables.set('randomItem', JSON.stringify(randomItem));
```

I know that for 03 2023 importing external libraries is in beta, but let's assume it works ok.

I understand that I need to create `filter`:

**First question:** where is option to create one? I wish it will be separated form my project code.

**Second question:** can I have filter **code** directly in my request (visible to quickly check what happening in request)? Or I need to create filters for every request where I need new custom code

I tried follow docs but there is no clear information where add files for filters: https://github.com/rangav/thunder-client-support/blob/master/docs/filters.md

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I partially figured it out because it looks like scripts are injected on Collection level.

Prerequisites - navigate to Thunder Client:

1. Create Environment (Env tab -> menu -> New Environment) let's call it **baseEnv**
2. In **baseEnv** set empty `v` variable and Save
3. Create Collection (Collection tab -> menu -> New Collection) let's call it **myCol**
4. In **myCol** go to menu -> Settings -> Environment and attach Environment **baseEnv**

Create script:

1. Decide where you will keep the scripts (i.e. separate repository)
2. Create file  i.e. script.js
3. Add function to script:

   ```js
   async function testFunc() {
       console.log("Test log message");
       return "TEST";
   }

   module.exports = [testFunc];
   ```

To add custom script to Collection:

1. Go to Collections and find your Collection
2. Open Collection menu (...)
3. Open Setting tab
4. Choose file with script
5. Save

Use script:

1. Crete request in Collection (menu -> New Request)
2. Url: https://httpbin.org/anything
3. In Headers add header  `A-test` with value: `{{v | testFunc}}` 
   [image]
4. Send request!

Result:
[image]

If script is not loaded and function was not executed try:

- load script again and save
- type expression `{{v | testFunc}}` and save

Extend scripts:

1. Place there files with 2 scripts:
2. Example file with script https://github.com/rangav/thunder-client-support/blob/master/docs/custom-filters.js
3. Example file with types https://github.com/rangav/thunder-client-support/blob/master/docs/tc-types.d.ts